# Secure another web app using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a web app Foo which is not secured, and I want to secure it using Flask, and more features will come also in this Flask app.

Foo is accessible via port 8081. Foo and this Flask web are in the same server.

Do I have to rewrite every end point in Foo as follows?

```
@app.route('/overview')
def foo_overview():
    if check_token():
        r = requests.get("http://localhost:8081/overview")
        return r.content
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

or is there a convenient way to open a tunnel to localhost?

```
@app.route('/')
def foo_app():
    if check_token():
        # port 8081 now is opened for this connection
        url = tunnel("http://localhost:8081")              
        return redirect(url)
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

My idea is to not open port 8081, but open 80, so users go from port 80 and if passing security check, they can start to use the service at 8081.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import stream_with_context

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def foo_app(path):
    if check_token():
        # port 8081 now is opened for this connection
        req = requests.get("http://localhost:8001/%s"%path, stream = True)
        return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type = req.headers['content-type'])
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

I borrowed most of this from http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/118/

Comment: This works with all endpoints except one which returns html page(contain JS as well), and this endpoint doesn't work because JS is continuous reloading and never stops. I googled but don't find a way to handle it.